# Ext JS 4 - cloning a node and append elsewhere in the DOM

Tags: javascript, dom, extjs, clone

I am trying to clone a `<thead>` element in Ext JS and append it to another location in the DOM.

I have this fiddle set up as an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/DUnWy/3/

Being new to the framework i am struggling a bit with the basics and cannot see why this code is not functioning for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Ext.select method returns an instance of an `Ext.CompositeElement`, which follows the [Composite Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern), meaning that it is an object that encapsulates multiple elements of the same type.  To access the first table header DOM element from an `Ext.select` you'd have to do something like:

```
Ext.select('.data-grid thead').first().dom
```

I'm not exactly sure why the `Ext.DomHelper.append` isn't working, but the following code works:

```
Ext.onReady(function() {

    var hdr = Ext.select('.data-grid thead').first().dom,
        cntr = Ext.select('.clone table').first().dom,
        clone = Ext.clone(hdr);

    cntr.appendChild(clone);

});​
```